# Will the first server be added as one of 5 nodes in OpenStack Autopilot?

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

## 1.

After reading [the documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot) for setting up OpenStack Autopilot,
I am instructed to install Ubuntu server on the first server.

But after going to MAAS GUI to add the other nodes, I don't know how to add the MAAS server (first server) as a node? Nothing concerning this is on the documentation.

Also is it **still** true that the first server (1 of 2) needs to have 2 network ports connected to it?

## 2.

Can I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (I know it is just beta 2) for OpenStack Autopilot now or I have to wait till the launch date of April 21st?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if the MAAS server counts as one of the 5 servers required to use Autopilot, you're correct.

**1.** You can't add maas as a node as far as I am aware.  Autopilot is meant to build the stack in an automated way, if you're capable of adding maas, you'll be doing it against the will of autopilot.  Additionally, your landscape server will not be used as a compute node either.  Autopilot does still require 2 servers having 2 network cards.

**2.** Openstack Installer 0.99.27 is in 16.04LTS, so you should be able to use it.  If you're building a test enviroment, go for it, but if you plan on taking it into production, I would either use 14.04, or wait for the full release.

Comment: So #1. maas server is 1 of the 2 servers and landscape is on the second server that require 2 network ports? `is that correct?` #2. no mention of autopilot version number anywhere on the website as far as i know..so where do i get that version of openstack? or i just have to follow same installation instructions? thanks a lot! P.S. I think canonical need to add that one need minimum 7 servers then not 5 if one cant add the maas and landscape servers..also the documentation page needs some editing

Comment: Correct, maas is one of the 2 server nics, at least how my stack was built.  However, landscape is not the other 2 nic servers.  There is another server that does't support the VMs, which I believe is primarily the neutron service for networking to the VMs.  All of my servers have 4 nics, so I'm not sure how it chose to pick them.

Comment: So with all these info you giving me, in your honest opinion, `how many physical servers are needed to setup the minimum cloud using openstack autopilot?` Doesn't look like it is 5 servers..and in what process/step does it choose the landscape server?..i only have 4 servers with 2 NICs and already have maas installed on one of them..i believed their documentation saying install on first server(of 5 according to their documentation)

Comment: also please `DON'T FORGET` to explain how to get that 16.04 LTS version of openstack autopilot..do i just follow same instructions but with 16.04 LTS beta 2 installed or there is a different installation route? Thanks! P.S. By the way this will be production(low grade production kinda), i am guessing i can update to full release version when it comes out right?

Comment: The minimum servers is 5, which includes the maas server.  So you're good there.  As far as picking the landscape server, I'm not sure how it picks it.  How I 'picked' which server would get landscape, based on the processing power of each server I had... Was I install maas, then I added one server to maas, which I then ran the openstack installer with only the one server.  That is where landscape was added, then I ran openstack through landscape after the rest of the hardware was deployed.

Comment: You'll get that version of openstack with just using apt-get.  That version is what is in the repo.  You'll be able to upgrade to LTS when it's released.  The release won't really change, so it's pretty safe, but with building something for high availability like a cloud environment, I would hesitate to start with a beta.  Although, based on how ubuntu is, I don't have a reason, besides it sounds funny.

Comment: wait so all i need is still 5 physical nodes? then how many nodes will actually be used for the cloud(as in compute, storage and all the components of openstack)? I mean i am so confused now..i thought all 5 nodes will all be used for the cloud which is how it does HA, because it spread things across `them`. I mean how will HA be setup then if all on just 5 servers and 1 server is already not among compute node and you mentioned landscape server making it `only 3 servers that are really compute nodes?`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  You need 5 physical machines to use autopilot.  You'll need 7 for High availability.  In a 5 server setup, you'll end up with 3 nodes where your services will be spread.  Each additional server you add from 5, you'll gain a usable node, and additional storage if you have local storage on that server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38105/discussion-between-babababa-and-brian).